# The Kernel crashes when I use np.float64

Tags: python

When I define the following code, and try to "apply" it to a dataframe, it gives me the above error, and when I change dtype from float64 to float32, I don't get any errors. What might be the issue?

```
def round(x):
    if x.dtype == np.float64:
        return round(x)
    else:
        return x
```

I am just following along a bootcamp, and this happened. I am using VS Code by the way

Comment: This results in infinite recursion, because `round` calls itself when the condition is true. You may want to change your function name to something other than `round`.

Comment: You are talking about "the above error", however there is no error given

Comment: you can use NumPy lib  np.round(x)

Comment: Probably you wanted to write `return np.round(x)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining the function `round` and then call it within itself (recursion) without any termination criteria.

A solution might be to name your function `my_round` or something different from the built-in function `round`. Or, as @tevemadar pointed out in the comment, use `np.round()`.

Comment: Thank you! I just realized my mistake. I will accept your answer once the time limit passes.